# Changing a data type in excel based on a variable

Tags: excel

I have a formula:
=IF($T$23="D",SUMIF('683378'!$B$14:$B$8099,A2,'683378'!$ED$14:$ED$8099)*$T$24,SUMIF('683378'!$B$14:$B$8099,A2,'683378'!$ED$14:$ED$8099))

I have a summary tab where $T$23="D" is either "D" for dollars or "U" for units which changes the calculations throughout the report.

Does anyone know how I can also get the data type to change when entering a D or a U to either currency or Number?

thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to change the cell formatting based on the selection of D (Dollar) or U (Unit). This can be done with Conditional Formatting.

1. Click **Conditional Formatting** then **New Rule**
2. Click **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**
3. In the Formula box enter the following formula `=Summary!$T$23="D"` (I guessed on the summary sheet name)
4. Click the **Format...** button
5. Format as **Currency** or whatever formatting you prefer and click **OK** then **OK** again
6. Repeat items 1-5 again for your unit formatting, changing the formula to `=Summary!$T$23="U"`

That should do it for you.